# how to convert text file into CSV file using c#

Tags: c#, csv, text-files, readline

I have an input file with fixed columns lengths and I need the file converted to csv using c# code.
The current code transforms to csv but the entire row data is not seperated by columns in csv instead stores complete row data values in single cell in each row in converted csv file.

Input text file:-

```
#Configuration: Tests
#Station                All                      1st                     2nd
#             Sat1   Sat2  Sat3           Sat1  Sat2  Sat3             Sat1  Sat2  Sat3
AA         92.88    95.14    93.16    98.31    98.98   100.00    91.31    94.17    93.16
BB         94.57    95.42    93.12    98.21    98.98    99.46    92.88    94.45    92.62
CC         93.26    95.00    92.99    98.49    99.26   100.00    91.85    94.30    92.99
```

The values should be stored in the similar way in csv file by text values seperated bycolumns.

```
            string sourcefile;
            string destfile;

            sourcefile=@"C:\\Temp\\NALabc.txt";
            destfile=@"C:\\Tempp\\NAL.csv";
            
            int i, j;       
            StreamWriter csvfile;
            string[] lines, cells;
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcefile);
            csvfile = new StreamWriter(destfile);
            for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                cells = lines[i].Split(new Char[] { '\t', ';' });
                for (j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
                    csvfile.Write(cells[j] + "\t");
                csvfile.WriteLine();
            }
            csvfile.Close();
```

Comment: I suggest you use a library like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Bit confused as to why you've included `;` in the delimiter chars when that doesn't appear in the example file you've shown?

Answer (score 0):

instead of splitting on tabs and semicolons split on spaces with empty entries removed.

Instead of looping and building the new lines just use string.Join - adding a line break only if it isn't the last line.

You can do all this by replacing your current for loop with this one:

```
for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
  cells = lines[i].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
  csvfile.Write(string.Join(',', cells) + 
    (i == lines.Length -1 ? "" : Environment.NewLine));
}
```

Comment: But I get the data as below, where the column headers are moving far away and they are not alligned with its column values. 
#                         Sat1              Sat2               Sat3                   Sat1        Sat2       Sat3             
AA         92.88    95.14    93.16    98.31    98.98   100.0            91.31    94.17    93.16
BB         94.57    95.42    93.12    98.21    98.98           99.46    92.88    94.45    92.62

Comment: Can you show what you mean by moving far away? In CSV columns are not horizontally aligned.

Comment: I mean to say that , from the above example of the input file,  if you can observe , we have a text named "Sat1" and in the same column there are values 92.88, 94.57 and 93.26. After converting to CSV file, the "Sat1" coulmn header is not alligned in the same column where we have the values 92.88,92.57 and 93.26 instead the column header"Sat 1" moves to the next columns after converting to CSV.

Comment: Are those tabs or spaces separating the columns in the original txt file?

Comment: Looks like the spaces seperating the columns in the original txt file

Comment: Then split on spaces and remove empties. (See updated answer)

Comment: I tried your latest code and get below conversion errors. Anyway, Thank you for the response. I will look into it.

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char' (CS1503) - 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char' (CS1503) - 
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) - 
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, params string[])' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) -

Comment: Double check that you've used the for loop from the answer. That error sounds like you might still using be `new Char[] {` in your call to `Split`.

Comment: I have made slight changes to the latest code which you have shared and it worked. 
Instead of cells = lines[i].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ); I have used string[] cells = lines[i].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ); which eventually worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yay! *high-five*

Comment: @navneet - is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted, thanks!